# Maven plugin version range isn't parsed correctly

Tags: java, maven, versioning

I specified the range below in my `pom.xml` properties

```
<version.range>[21.2.0,21.2.1)</version.range>
```

I can confirm there is a version that matches the range.  However, when running `mvn install`, it is throwing the error

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/x/y/z/abc/plugin/%5B21.2.0,21.2.1)/abc-%5B21.2.0,21.2.1).pom
```

It seems it's unable to parse the version.range above.  Why?

Note: this is a plugin dependency.

Comment: MCVE, please; we need at least the stanza where you're using this.

Comment: Apart from that I strongly recommend to prevent using version ranges please a full example as mentioned by @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-  Also you say via the version range: `[21.2.0` means to include that limit but via `21.2.1)` you say not to include the upper limit... now the question is: Do exist versions between `21.2.0` and `21.2.1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.  As it turned out, a version range is only supported for a dependency, but not for a plugin.  Using it for a plugin would cause the issue as above as Maven can't interpret and understand the version range.  It's also considered as bad practice by [the Maven community](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/plugin-version-ranges-errors-with-Maven-3-1-1-td5777583.html).